# MySQL Subqueries issue

Tags: mysql

To make this example simple, lets pretend my table has the following attributes.

Table

```
ID: Int
Amount: Int
nameId: Int
```

Records Ex

```
ID: 1
Amount: 2
nameId: 3

ID: 2
Amount: 2
nameId: 3

ID: 3
Amount: 1
nameId: 3
```

Currently I have the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(amount) FROM server.`inventory` where nameid = 558
```

It gives me

```
Amount 1
Amount 2
```

Straight forward, it selects a unique records base on amount. However, how can I also include in my query so that it counts how many id's are using that amount with nameid 558

So the output should be

```
Amount 1, Used 1
Amount 2, Used 2
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with subqueries?

Answer (score 1):

This is an aggregation query.  You want `group by` and `count()`:

```
SELECT amount, COUNT(*)
FROM server.inventory 
WHERE nameid = 558
GROUP BY amount;
```